# VBA using COUNTIFS as a formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I use `=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,">"&$B2)+COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)`
This function to rank within the group.
I try to use it as

```
Worksheets("A").Range("A1").Formula ="=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,">"&$B2)+COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)"
```

but it just return me True/False not the function .
I want to write this function on the cell and auto fill it to the last row.

Thank you

Comment: You need to double up the quotes inside your formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happened here?

If you look closely to your code and add it to your editor

```
Worksheets("A").Range("A1").Formula ="=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,">"&$B2)+COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)"
```

it will automatically add some spaces as below

```
Worksheets("A").Range("A1").Formula = "=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8," > "&$B2)+COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)"
```

So you can clearly see it consists of 4 parts:

1. `Worksheets("A").Range("A1").Formula` a reference to a cells formula
2. `=` an operator
3. `"=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,"` String1
4. `>` another operator
5. `"&$B2)+COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)"` String2

So what happens is that Excel compares the 2 strings with `>` because this is not part of the formula which ended with the second `"`. So `String1 > String2` is either `True` or `False`.

#### Solution

To include the `>` into your formula you need to double the quotes in your string.

```
Worksheets("A").Range("A1").Formula = "=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,"">""&$B2)+COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)"
```

Now `"=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,"">""&$B2)+COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)"` is considered as one whole string.

Answer (score -1):

The $B2 in the first COUNTIF must be text to concate with ">". So the formula should be something like this.

[Image of the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfXoH.png)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why do you add the formula as image? Please edit your answer and put it as text.

Comment: In additon to what @FunThomas said this might explain why: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) • And actually I don't get why you put an extra `&""&` in that formula, which is not needed. The OP just needs to replace `">"&$B2` with `"">""&$B2` in his code. Furthermore if you concatenate a string with a number eg `result = ">" & 5` the number will implicitly converted into a string and is the same as `result = ">5"`.